# Why can't I stop vim from wrapping my code?

Tags: vim

I can't stop vim from wrapping my Python code. If I enter `:set nowrap` like a champ, but it still wraps.

I can hit <kbd>J</kbd> to unite the split lines of code, so it seems like a real carriage return is being inserted. I just don't understand why or how to stop it.

Comment: `:set nowrap` only prevents it from wrapping the display of lines, not from inserting linebreaks.

Comment: For multiple windows, run: `:windo set nowrap`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
'textwidth' 'tw'        number  (default 0)
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
        Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
        broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
        this.  'textwidth' is set to 0 when the 'paste' option is set.  When
        'textwidth' is zero, 'wrapmargin' may be used.  See also
        'formatoptions' and |ins-textwidth|.
        When 'formatexpr' is set it will be used to break the line.
        NOTE: This option is set to 0 when 'compatible' is set.


'wrapmargin' 'wm'       number  (default 0) 
                        local to buffer
        Number of characters from the right window border where wrapping
        starts.  When typing text beyond this limit, an <EOL> will be inserted
        and inserting continues on the next line.
        Options that add a margin, such as 'number' and 'foldcolumn', cause
        the text width to be further reduced.  This is Vi compatible.
        When 'textwidth' is non-zero, this option is not used. 
        See also 'formatoptions' and |ins-textwidth|.  {Vi: works differently
        and less usefully}
```

If you refer to auto wrapping of long lines sending them to the next one, try

```
:set textwidth=0 
:set wrapmargin=0
```

Comment: Some plugins seem to override this setting.

Comment: The `tw` and `wp` options didn't really work out for me so I had to go for `formatoptions` https://github.com/ain/.vim/blob/28c71b23a3914ff298e5cc5f7aa2a82abc9f0fb9/.vimrc#L12

Comment: If tw and wp still doesn't solve the problem have a look at this post on SU which helped me solve my problem:
http://superuser.com/questions/250112/textwidth-0-and-wrapwidth-0-in-vimrc-local-not-being-respected

Comment: Removing `filetype plugin on` from my `.vimrc` did it for me.

Comment: With this answer, you cannot use `gq` to realign the paragraph manually to textwidth. @Engineero's should be the correct one.

Answer (score 126):

None of the other answers worked for me (IDK why).

**`:set wrap!`** Did the trick for me (using GVim for Windows).

Comment: This solves a slightly different problem. `wrap` provides the appearance of line wrapping, but doesn't _actually_ break text onto new lines. You likely had `wrap` enabled, so `:set wrap!` toggled it off. You can check with `:set wrap?` which will echo the current value (i.e. `wrap` or `nowrap`).

Comment: This solution works for me at Mac OsX. Vim version 7.4

Comment: This worked for me, I changed `textwidth` and `wrapmargin` first but this actually forced vim to update and rerender without any wrapped lines.

Comment: Ding din ding! Works in neovim

Comment: What a magical moment when you find out that the command you really need is so expressive and simple. Thanks devs

Comment: I can confirm that this is working on GVim on Archlinux.

Comment: Works in `neovim`

Comment: At say's @shadowtalker, to keep it use `set nowrap`

Answer (score 79):

`set formatoptions-=t` should do the trick. `set formatoptions+=t` will turn auto-wrapping back on.

For more information on what you can do with `formatoptions`, see [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table).

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is the only one that worked for me. No longer does vim insert newlines sometimes when I enter insert mode.

Comment: Yup. This is the real solution.

Comment: To turn off auto wrapping in a markdown file, I had to use `set formatoptions=cq` as explained by @Ain_Tohvri in a comment under another answer.

Answer (score 34):

For preventing vim from wrapping long lines I use these two lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
set nowrap           " do not automatically wrap on load
set formatoptions-=t " do not automatically wrap text when typing
```

Comment: `set nowrap` is the only one that worked for me. in neovim

Answer (score 15):

To disable line wrap, you can enter
`:set wrap!` or append this command to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: This does not affect the automatic insertion of real line breaks, which this question is about.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it's the textwidth that's set, which automatically breaks lines when it reaches a certain length
Try

```
:set tw=0
```

If that fails play with e.g.

```
:set wrap linebreak textwidth=0
```

and

```
:set virtualedit=insert
```

Comment: wrap and linebreak don't insert actual end-of-lines into the buffer, so that doesn't seem to be his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vim may have to be in [vi-compatible mode](http://forums.devshed.com/unix-help-35/how-to-not-wrap-lines-in-vi-for-viewing-50175.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open vimrc_example.vim (Yes, this is the file in Vim74) and set textwidth=0.

Answer (score 0):

On macbook pro I outcommented in .vimrc the line

```
autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
```

so it became

```
"  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78
```

.

(I installed a version of vim via homebrew.)
This helped for all .txt files.