# default automatic line break for python files in vim

Tags: vim

When I edit a **python** file in vim, `formatoptions` is set to `tcq` for some reason making it automatically break long lines in code which sometimes may break the code as well. This is in contrary to other code filetypes such as **c** or **java** where automatic line breaks only occur in comments. I can disable this by removing `t` from `formatoptions` but I was wondering why the default behavior is set to this for **python** files?

Also where are `formatoptions` are set for different filetypes?

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290285/why-cant-i-stop-vim-from-wrapping-my-code ?

Comment: @CalvinCheng close but not the answer I was looking for. I don't have to set anything with my c or java files even though I have `tw` and `wm` set. it sounds like a bug to me or I just don't see the point..

Answer (score 1):

Use `:verbose set <option>` to see where it's set.

If it's in a default file: don't touch it, just set the correct value in your `~/.vimrc`.

If it's in some third party script: see why it's set that way, try the desired value, see if it breaks anything.

***edit***

I'm dumb as a rock. Do you hear me? *Dumb. As. A. Rock.*

`tcq` is simply the default value of `formatoptions`. I guess `~/.vimrc` is a (non-intuitive) way for Vim to say that.

The default Python ftplugin doesn't set it to another value so you'll have to do that yourself. Here is what I have in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal smartindent
setlocal formatoptions=croql
setlocal cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

Comment: it says `~/.vimrc` but I don't have anything set in it

Comment: so for other file types such as c, it gives me `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/c.vim` but for python it says `.~/.vimrc` which is not true, or at least it doesn't give me anything useful because it's not in that file.

Comment: Vim wouldn't point to that file if the option was not set there. You should post your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: It's not there. Do you have non-commited/pushed changes? Is your `~/.vimrc` a symlink to the `vimrc` in your repo? I see you have activated modelines, do the python files have modelines?

Comment: (1)I don't have non-commited/pushed changes. (2)yes, ~/.vimrc is a symlink to `vimrc`. (3)It happens with python files without modelines. (4)Can you try it on your vim to see if you have the same problem? I highly doubt this is related to my vim configuration.

Comment: glad to hear I'm not the only one. I think `croql` makes much more sense than `tcq` for python files as default. thanks for confirming, you're no dumb =)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the after/ftplugin set of files.  I'd been doing all of that sort of thing with autocmds in my vimrc.