# Editing a file that is wider than the screen in Linux

Tags: linux, editing

I'm trying to edit a text file in Linux. The lines are quite long and vi insists on wrapping the lines. I'd like to see the lines NOT wrapped. I realize I'll have to scroll right and left some but that's okay; the lines are not so wide that this is a big problem. I can't see any options for vi that would make it display a file without wrapping the lines.

How do I accomplish this?

By the way, I am not determined to use vi and only vi. Any other standard editor/tool on Linux that can do what I want is fine by me. I'm afraid my Linux knowledge is skimpy.

I'm not sure what distribution of Linux is running nor how to do find out but if you can tell me a command that will determine that, I'll be happy to run it. I expect each distro may have somewhat different tools/commands.

Comment: In vim execute next command: `:set nowrap`. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290285/why-cant-i-stop-vim-from-wrapping-my-code).

Answer (score 2):

`:h wrap` in vim says `:set nowrap`.

Comment: By the way, I tried :set nowrap (and :set wrap) in vi and they work there too.

Comment: Only because `vi` is an alias to `vim` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs hash the `visual-line-mode`, which presents the lines as if wrapped, but keeping them long in fact.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html

Comment: Yikes! I'm not sure how but I've gotten myself into trouble in the edit session. It keeps prompting me to complete a prompt for "eval" and I have no idea what it wants or how to get out of emacs. (I've never used emacs in my life.) Can you tell me how to get back out of the file? The vim solution posted above meets my needs perfectly.

Comment: Ignore my previous "Yikes" comment. I found an emacs tutorial and learned how to exit emacs the right way. It turned out that I took the instructions at the linked page too literally and actually typed the characters M-x visual line mode instead of doing what I should have done. (I get that "c-x" means control-x but I'm still not clear on how to do an "m-x".) It doesn't matter though.The :set nowrap and :set wrap in vim (and vi) do exactly what I need.