# Vim automatically goes to next line past column 80 with Fortran files

Tags: vim, fortran

I know the "standard" wants the terminal to have a maximum of 80 columns [(see this question)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width), but I have now extended that limit to 100 columns (with `set colorcolumn=101`). However, **only** when working with `.f90` fortran files , when typing past column 80, vim automatically takes the last word I was writing and goes to the next line. Is there a way to disable that feature?

I have made more than a few changes to my `~/.vimrc` file but I canceled all of them to make sure it wasn't something I have done.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, there was a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290285/why-cant-i-stop-vim-from-wrapping-my-code). From the answers provided, `textwidth` and `wrapmargin` should do the trick but they don't. I have removed every line from my `~/.vimrc` file to add `set textwidth=0` and `set wrapmargin=0` as suggested, but the problem persists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I stop vim from wrapping my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290285/why-cant-i-stop-vim-from-wrapping-my-code)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Is that what "wrapping a code" means? Anyway, I had already tried adding `set textwidth=0 warpmargin=0` but it did not work

Comment: I don't know what "wrapping a code" means. I assume that either vim is inserting line breaks, or visually wrapping (display only not really editing the buffer), both of which are covered by that question. If it's not a proper duplicate, please edit your question to reflect **all** that you've tried, and why this is a different situation.

Comment: You mention a "standard" of 80 character lines, but in this case there is an actual published standard that fixed-form Fortran lines are exactly 72 characters long and free-form Fortran lines are a maximum of 132 characters.  (ISO/IEC 1539:2010 cl 3.3.3.1 and cl 3.3.2.1)

Comment: You've still entirely ignored visual word wrapping. Have you disabled it or not?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What command is that? I have tried every thing that was provided in the answer of the question you said mine is a duplicate of and nothing worked.

Comment: @casey Then the standard is not even respected in my case as a maximum of 80 characters is enforced here.

Comment: `:set nowrap` as mentioned in the linked question body as well as the top comment.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist yes I have, nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track with `textwidth`, but you need to set it after the Fortran syntax is setup.  Set up a file at `~/.vim/after/syntax/fortran.vim` and put `set textwidth=0` in that file.

Comment: That did the trick! I created those directories and `set textwidth=0` in the `fortran.vim` file solved my issue, without the need to add `let fortran_free_source=1` to my `.vimrc`. Thank you for your help